# Can someone help me figure out why a simulated circuit I made wont work on Tinkercad?

Tags: transistors, led, capacitor, simulation

[image: This is a picture of that circuit I built from a diagram]

[image: The diagram]

I'm trying to build a circuit on Tinkercad, which I'm pretty sure is known as an astable multivibrator, but whenever I try to simulate it, either the says capacitors are inversely polarized, the LED's don't blink, which they are supposed to, or the circuit is unable to simulate.

Can someone help me figure out whether this circuit is wrong or if it's an issue with the simulator?

EDIT: I've added an image of the circuit without the capacitors so you can see whats under them.

[image: Diagram without capacitors covering it]

Comment: Should I remove both and upload an image or just the left one?

Comment: Ok, I've added a picture with the capacitors moved out of the way

Comment: Are you sure the LEDs are the right way around? (it's impossible to tell from that toy simulator's breadboard layout). I put your circuit into [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html) and it simulated perfectly.

Comment: Yes, the LEDs are in the right position, with the cathode on the negative side and the anode on the positive. I've managed to make the circuit work on other simulators thanks to Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75, but on the simulator I'm using, Tinkercad, the capacitors still are negatively polarized.

Comment: I mean inversely polarized

Comment: I put diodes in my LTspice simulation like Tony Stewart suggested and it worked perfectly, no native voltage on the capacitors. Perhaps you need a better simulator?

Answer (score 2):

1) Since Vbe > Vce there is a reverse polarity on the e-Caps.  In practice tantalums can handle 10% reverse voltage, not sure about Alum.

[There are ways to avoid this adding diodes to Vce.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%204%200.000054999999999999995%2025.510281670702206%2050%205%2050%0Aw%20112%2048%20208%2048%200%0Aw%20208%2048%20288%2048%200%0Aw%20288%2048%20384%2048%200%0Ar%20112%2096%20112%20176%200%20470%0Ar%20208%2048%20208%20176%200%2030000%0Ar%20288%2048%20288%20176%200%2030000%0Ar%20384%2096%20384%20176%200%20470%0Aw%20208%20176%20320%20256%200%0Aw%20288%20176%20160%20256%200%0AR%20112%2048%2064%2048%200%200%2040%209%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20112%20288%20112%20304%200%0Ag%20384%20288%20384%20304%200%0Ax%20152%20231%20173%20234%204%2016%20C1%0Ax%20317%20213%20338%20216%204%2016%20C2%0Ax%2085%20260%20106%20263%204%2016%20Q1%0Ax%20390%20259%20411%20262%204%2016%20Q2%0A162%20384%2048%20384%2096%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0A403%20416%2064%20544%20128%200%2016_256_0_4354_2.5_0.025_0_2_16_3%0A403%20416%20144%20544%20176%200%2016_256_0_4353_5_0.025_0_2_16_3%0At%20320%20256%20384%20256%200%201%20-8.240925172758297%20-0.3434064288504027%20100%0At%20160%20256%20112%20256%200%201%200.5451217440982697%200.6645198783731285%20100%0A162%20112%2048%20112%2096%202%20default-led%201%201%200%200.01%0A209%20112%20176%20208%20176%200%200.00001%201.0482507717652616%201%0A209%20384%20176%20288%20176%200%200.00001%207.232998895708958%201%0Ad%20112%20176%20112%20240%202%20default%0Ad%20384%20176%20384%20240%202%20default%0Aw%20112%20272%20112%20288%200%0Aw%20384%20272%20384%20288%200%0Ao%2020%20256%204%204354%2010%200.1%200%201%0Ao%2023%20256%200%204354%2010%200.1%201%202%2023%203%0A38%209%200%203.3%209%20Voltage%0A)

2)  Current gain must be 33%< Ai< 50% of hFE as rated  saturation assumes 10% hFE.

Otherwise It wont saturate or demand too big a cap.

Change 47k to 30 k

[image]

Darlingtons work the best.

Comment: can you  see schematic?

Comment: Here's another way but reduces ramp and increases f  http://tinyurl.com/sotoqwj

Comment: If you can choose the Rb/Rc ratio for your supply to ensure Vce>= Vbe then Vc >0  (actually Ib/Ic ratio as % of rated hFE)

Comment: Please tell us what simulator you used, and whether you added diodes like you suggested.  I can't tell from what I see if the lower diodes are the regulars and the "Lights" on top are where you moved the LED's or whether the diodes on the bottom are the LED's and the lights on top are "probes" and for getting the traces you display.

Comment: You said darlingtons work best.  Would a complementary darlington be just as good?  And a darlington fashioned from discretes -- does that matter?  Or is it just the high effective hFE?  Thanks.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I would also be interested to know which simulation software you were using for this. And would you be able to share the file for this circuit? Thanks!

Comment: @ndbroadbent  the sim is a falstad javascript provided with user input

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/2flsyqyz

Answer (score 2):

I tried this circuit also and got same error result. I am pretty sure that my connections are correct. I think TinkerCad's algorithm doesn't support this.

Comment: @All - For those users flagging this as "not an answer" (NAA), it does seem to be responding to the part of the question where it asks: "*if it's an issue with the simulator?*" so it doesn't meet the criteria for flagging as NAA. || The redstone jack - Welcome :-) As you are new here, you can see the [tour], [help] & [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931) for info about the site. If you have any more detail you can add to your answer, then you can [edit] it to add that. Thanks.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The TinkerCad's simulation fails for this circuit with the following error logged in the console:
`Trouble in the transient analysis loop, aborting, too many iterations needed.`

Comment: That's a shame, I've always wanted to properly understand how these astable multivibrator circuits work, and was hoping that I could set up some virtual oscilloscopes and multimeters in TinkerCad to see how everything worked. One of the other answers shows a working simulation, but I'm not sure what software they are using (and it might not run on my Mac.)

I might just have to set it up on a breadboard with some real components and get an oscilloscope.